# Проблема со стилизацией кнопки

Tags: android

Итак, я хочу сделать кнопку, на которой были бы картинки, но также чтобы была какая-то реакция на нажатие. Я нашел способ: использовал `ImageButton`, где в атрибуте `background` я установил системную реакцию на нажатие `attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`, а в `src` установил нужную мне картинку. Но получилось так, что картинки не подходят под размер моей кнопки (все изображения я залил в `mipmap`), они либо слишком маленькие, либо слишком большие, т.к. размер моей кнопки нестандартный (`35dp`).

И я вроде как уже нашел решение - использовать вместо `ImageButton` обычный `Button`, т.к. туда изображения автоматически подгоняются по размеру, но проблема в том, что т.к. я ставлю картинку в `background`, то я, получается, не могу установить атрибут для реакции кнопки на нажатие (который я устанавливал в `background` в `ImageButton`). И вот я не знаю как решить эту дилемму. Что вы посоветуете?

P.S. : Предложения по перерисовке изображения под нужный размер не принимаются, т.к. я хочу, чтобы на разных экранах все тоже хорошо смотрелось, а, следовательно, использование одноразмерного изображения на разных девайсах нецелесообразно.

**Код разметки:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
          android:id="@+id/bottom_bar">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:background="@color/Black"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageButton
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_dictionary"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/dicts"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:onClick="onClick (ReaderActivity)"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_underline"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:onClick="onClick (ReaderActivity)"
            android:id="@+id/highlighting"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_list"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/chapters"
            android:onClick="onClick (ReaderActivity)"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_day_night"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/switchMode"
            android:onClick="onClick (ReaderActivity)"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:id="@+id/rotate"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_rotation"
            android:layout_width="35dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `ImageButton` нужно использовать `src` вместо `background` для показа картинки

```
android:src="@drawable/image"
```

Соответственно с реакцией нажатия проблем нет

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Кстати, если эффект нажатия будет в `background`, то при касании он будет показан под картинкой. Чтобы он был **над** картинкой вместо `background` нужно использовать `foreground`. И, вообще, зачем вам эффект касания, если в `ImageButton` он предусмотрен по умолчанию?

**UPDATE**

Если картинки не сочетаются с размером кнопки, то вы можете поместить `Button` и `ImageView` в `FrameLayout`

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">           
<Button
android:layout_width="35dp"
android:layout_height="35dp" />
<ImageView
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/image"
android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Можно сделать кликабельный `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="35dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:src="@drawable/image"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
/>
```

`clickable` сделает картинку кликабельной, тоесть вы можете ей установить слушатель `OnClickListener` (на заметку `focusable` слелает возможность поставить слушатель долгого нажатия `OnLongClickListener`. Остальные атрибуты, думаю Вам известны.

Comment: Во-первых не предусмотрен, уж в этом я уверен.
Во-вторых я сказал почему не хочу использовать ImageButton, т.к. если например картинка маленькая то она не растягивается до размеров кнопки, а если большая, то она просто напросто обрезается

Comment: Внимательнее читайте вопрос

Comment: @Ник, сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: @Ник, а сейчас?

Comment: @Ник, эффект нажатия предусмотрен по умолчанию как в `Button`, так и в `ImageButton`. Если вы поменяете `background`, то конечно же о пропадет

Comment: Да, но когда в backround устанавливается картинка, то эффект пропадает

Comment: @Ник, кнопки не предназначены для картинок в `background`. Для кнопки с картинкой есть `ImageButton` и свойство `src`. `background` вам не нужен, не будете трогать - будет эффект

Comment: Я понимаю, но я же написал, что ImageButton не подгоняет картинку под свой размер, а обычный Button подгоняет

Comment: @Ник, кстати а зачем вам вообще фон для кнопки с картинкой? По последнему писку моды кнопки представляют собой кликабельные `ImageView`, могу дополнить этим ответ

Comment: Не знал об этом, было бы не плохо если бы вы дополнили

Comment: @Ник, ну так положите `ImageView` с картинкой и `Button` в `FrameLayout` указав им одинаковые размеры (ну, у картинки чуть поменьше, чтоб она заподлицо не была)

Comment: @Ник, дополнил ответ

Comment: Ну так я не могу сделать ибо у меня все кнопки в LinearLayout. Если я их туда положу, то FrameLayout растянется

Comment: Скиньте полную разметку в вопрос, ничего так непонятно

Comment: @Ник, кстати вы можете юзать `Button`, просто в `background` картинку установить, а в `foreground` эффект нажатия, все равно эффект над картинкой должен быть. А вообще вроде есть некий `layer-list`, с помощью него можно установить и картинку и эффект (вроде)

Comment: Так, я добавил разметку

Comment: @Ник, зачем вам `ImageButton` в `FrameLayout`, если это контейнер и должен иметь минимум 2 вью?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55208/discussion-between-flippy-and-).